# textAlign will not move button (or other components) - Dash

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash, text-align

I am fairly new to dash and am trying to use textAlign to move components. I can't seem to get it working in any case - here is an example:

```
           html.Div([
                dbc.Col([
                    html.Div([                           
                        dbc.Button('Plex-ecute ;)', id=f'plex_execute', color='danger', outline=True,
                                        block=True, style={'height':'100px'})                            
                    ])
                ],style={'textAlign':'right'})
```

I have tried putting the style section in multiple areas, in this case it is in a parent column. Each time, the page runs but the component does not move - any ideas on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue turned out to be the nested Col/Row/Divs. Without the function being in a 'Col', there is no instruction to centre the text against. A solution in this case turned out to be:

```
dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col([
        dbc.Button(BUTTON_INFO, style={'textAlign':'right'})
    ])
])
```

In short, it seems to help by having the final function in a column, then having as little before that as possible.